Suddenly receivers-email ID doesn't receive any Email
I have developed a php application on a Linux server, everything works ok from months,the application work okay and send emails via a button to customers(receivers), Suddenly, I can't send any email reminders from my PHP application to my customers.
Note 1: that when I send an email via the command line (echo "Corps de l'email" | mail -s "Sujet de l'email" dev3@gmail.com), I receive the email successfully.
Note 2: when i type  sudo journalctl -u postfix -xe , it gives me:
May 27 16:20:40 rdev70 systemd[1]: postfix.service: Succeeded.

Subject: Unit succeeded
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-The unit postfix.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.

Note 3 :  when i type **sudo systemctl status postfix   , it gives me
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Mon 2024-05-27 15:24:57 CEST; 54min ago
Process: 2764 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 2764 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
May 27 15:24:57 rdev70 systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
May 27 15:24:57 rdev70 systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Note 4:
when i type sudo grep -i "error" /var/log/mail.log, it gives me :
May 26 22:08:06 rdev70 postfix/smtpd[13203]: SSL_accept error from lputeaux-658-1-30-140.w80-13.abo.wanadoo.fr[80.13.153.140]: lost connection
Note 5: when i type sudo grep -i "warning" /var/log/mail.log, it gives me :
May 28 17:00:36 rdev70 postfix/smtpd[17742]: warning: xsasl_cyrus_server_get_mechanism_list: no applicable SASL mechanisms
May 28 17:00:37 rdev70 postfix/master[14533]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtpd pid 17742 exit status 1

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).
